# Calculating time difference

Tags: google-sheets

I have 4 columns on my sheet.

```
A           B           C           D
10/10/2016  10:21:00 PM 10/11/2016  11:31:00 AM
```

How do I calculate this time difference? The simple formula `=D-B` is giving me a negative value.

Answer (score 3):

In all spreadsheet programs time is stored internally as a fraction of a day. Dates are stored as floating point number counting up from a specific day.

In your case you have split the dates and times into different cells. This means that when you subtract Column D from column B the program doesn't know about the date so it dutifully  says that 11:31 AM comes before 10:21 PM and gives you a negative result. Because you are formatting the result as a number you see it as negative.

To get the value you expect you want to use the following formula to recombine the date and the time before doing the subtraction:

```
=C1+D1-(A1+B1)
```

If you format this as a number is will show you:

```
0.5486111111
```

To get in hours multiply it by 24 to get 13.16666667